# Using a Lens to read multiple fields

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

Given the types

```
data Prisoner = P { _name   :: String
                  , _rank   :: Int
                  , _cereal :: Cereal }

data Cereal = C { _number             :: Int
                , _percentDailyValue  :: Map String Float
                , _mascot             :: String }
```

I could extract someone's name, rank, and cereal number via pattern matching:

```
getNameRankAndCerealNumber_0 :: Prisoner -> (String, Int, Int)
getNameRankAndCerealNumber_0 (P { _name=name
                                , _rank=rank
                                , _cereal = C { _number=cerealNumber }}
                             ) = (name, rank, cerealNumber)
```

Alternately, I could use lenses to extract each part separately

```
makeLenses ''Cereal
makeLenses ''Prisoner

getNameRankAndCerealNumber_1 :: Prisoner -> (String, Int, Int)
getNameRankAndCerealNumber_1 p = (p ^. name, p ^. rank, p ^. cereal.number)
```

Is there a way to extract all three simultaneously in a single traversal of the data structure?

Some way to combine `Getter`s, `Getter s a -> Getter s b -> Getter s (a,b)`?

Comment: Do you mean "serial number" or is this some joke that I'm not getting?

Comment: Tom Ellis: It's just a bad pun.

Comment: my original inspiration was [the use of pattern matching that this pull request tries to make work with ghc 7.8.*](https://github.com/schell/hdevtools/pull/1). If the code had used field extractors or lenses, it wouldn't have been needed to be fixed.

Comment: Mad Physicist: [done](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26793455/9859). Is that what meta.stackoverflow recommends for this scenario?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

We can use the `Applicative` instance of the `ReifiedGetter` newtype from [`Control.Lens.Reified`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.5/docs/Control-Lens-Reified.html):

```
runGetter $ (,) <$> Getter number <*> Getter mascot
```

In general, the newtypes in `Control.Lens.Reified` offer a lot of very useful instances for getters and folds.

**Note#1**: Notice that we are combining the lenses as getters, and getting a getter in return. You can't obtain a composite lens in this way, as there would be problems if their "focuses" overlap. What could be the proper setter behaviour in that case?

**Note#2**: The [alongside](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.5/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v:alongside) function lets you combine two lenses, getting a bona-fide lens that works on the two halves of a product. This is different form the previous case because we can be sure the lenses don't overlap. `alongside` comes in handy when your type is a tuple or has an isomorphism to a tuple.

Comment: Thanks! I hope you don't mind, I fleshed out your answer a bit in the question.

Answer (score 7):

Fleshing out [danidiaz's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26723075/9859), I was able to construct a `Getter Prisoner (String, Int, Int)` using `ReifiedGetter`:

```
getNameRankAndCerealNumber_2 :: Prisoner -> (String, Int, Int)
getNameRankAndCerealNumber_2 = p ^. nameRankAndCerealNumber_2

nameRankAndCerealNumber_2 :: Getter Prisoner (String, Int, Int)
nameRankAndCerealNumber_2 = runGetter ((,,) <$> Getter name <*> Getter rank <*> Getter (cereal.number))
```

And a `Lens' Prisoner (String, Int, Int)` using `alongside`, though I had to manually construct `Iso'`s between `Prisoner` and an `HList [String, Int, Int]` and between `HList [a,b,c]` and `(a,b,c)`.

```
getNameRankAndCerealNumber_3 :: Prisoner -> (String, Int, Int)
getNameRankAndCerealNumber_3 p = p ^. nameRankAndCerealNumber_3

setNameRankAndCerealNumber_3 :: (String, Int, Int) -> Prisoner -> Prisoner
setNameRankAndCerealNumber_3 t p = p & nameRankAndCerealNumber_3 .~ t

nameRankAndCerealNumber_3 :: Lens' Prisoner (String, Int, Int)
nameRankAndCerealNumber_3 = hlist . alongside id (alongside id number) . triple
  where triple :: Iso' (a,(b,c)) (a,b,c)
        triple = dimap (\(a,(b,c)) -> (a,b,c)) (fmap $ \(a,b,c) -> (a,(b,c)))
        hlist :: Iso' Prisoner (String, (Int, Cereal))
        hlist = dimap (\(P n r c) -> (n,(r,c))) (fmap $ \(n,(r,c)) -> P n r c)
```

There may be an easier way to do this, but that's another question.