# Selecting the fields of a tuple using lenses (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, lenses

The following does not work, how do I fix it?

```
Prelude Control.Lens> (2, 3, 4) ^. alongside _1 _2

<interactive>:19:14:
    Couldn't match type ‘(s0, s'0)’ with ‘(t0, t1, t2)’
    Expected type: Getting (a, a') (t0, t1, t2) (a, a')
      Actual type: LensLike
                     (Const (a, a')) (s0, s'0) (t3, t'0) (a, a') (a, a')
    In the second argument of ‘(^.)’, namely ‘alongside _1 _2’
    In the expression: (2, 3, 4) ^. alongside _1 _2
```

What I wanted was `(2, 3)`.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26722458/using-a-lens-to-read-multiple-fields/26723075#26723075 `alongside` only works with a two-element tuple.

Comment: Did you want a getter or a full lens?