# How to combine lenses (not compose)

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

In haskell without lenses I can do things like :

```
data Item = Item { quantity :: Double, price ::Double }

cost :: Item -> Double
cost = (*) <$> quantity <*> price
```

If I use lenses instead how can I do the equivalent ? The best I can do is

```
cost = to $ (*) <$> (^. quantity) <*> (^. price)
```

Is there a better way ? (of course I want a `getter` or equivalent)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `cost = (*) <$> (^. quantity) <*> (^. price)`?

Comment: You could always create two new operators: `f <$>. l = f <$> (^. l)` and `f <*>. l = f <*> (^. l)`. Then your expression becomes `cost = (*) <$>. quantity <*>. price`.

Comment: It's not any shorter, but using `Control.Lens` you can do `cost = returnA &&& returnA >>> view (alongside quantity price) >>> uncurry (*)`.  The `returnA &&& returnA` is equivalent to `\a -> (a, a)` but more generalized, `alongside quantity price :: Lens' (Item, Item) (Double, Double)`, then `uncurry (*)` is pretty self explanatory.  This solution does not scale beyond 2 lenses, though.  For that @AaditMShah's suggestion is better, but I would prefer `^$^` and `^*^` since the `^` symbol usually indicates a getter in `lens`, and if you use `view` instead of `^.` it'll have a more general type.

Comment: @AaditMShah yes of course. I updated it.

Comment: @AaditMShah I also want a lens like which why I start with a `to`.

Comment: You can't make `cost` a lens because a lens must have both a getter and a setter. However, `cost` only has a getter. To set the cost you need to update both `quantity` and/or `price`. Hence, there's no "correct" way to create a setter for `cost`. Therefore, `cost` cannot be a lens. It can only be a function of the type `Item -> Double` (i.e. a getter).

Comment: That why i put `lens like`, not `lens` ;-).

Comment: @bekhlir I think your solution just give a function `Item -> Double`. I'm looking for a getter.

Comment: A variation on @bheklilr 's suggestion: `to (join (,)) . alongside quantity price . to (uncurry (*))`

Comment: Why are you posting answers as comments?

Comment: @Bakuriu to not risk getting down voted I presume ;-)

Comment: @Bakuriu My guess would be that no one believes their answer is better than mb14's original idea...

Comment: I just stumbled upon [this answer by @danidiaz](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26723075/2751851) which suggests [`Control.Lens.Reified`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.13/docs/Control-Lens-Reified.html): the wrappers for read-only optics there have the instances that you'd expect for a function, so you can do `runGetter ((*) <$> Getter quantity <*> Getter price)`.

Comment: @duplode seems promising, even though it's much shorter than the `to ... view` version. What's annyoing is this `to .. view` back and forth conversion is crying for an `iso` but I haven't figured out how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

It just occurred to me that you don't need any special syntax to combine lenses. If you are creating lenses using Template Haskell (which you should be doing) then you already have primitive getters for each field, preceded by an underscore.

Hence, you could use the primitive getters to create your phantom `cost` getter as follows:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens

data Item = Item { _quantity :: Double
                 , _price    :: Double
                 }

$(makeLenses ''Item)

cost :: Getter Item Double
cost = to $ (*) <$> _quantity <*> _price

item :: Item
item = Item { _quantity = 2, _price = 5.0 }

main :: IO ()
main = print $ view cost item
```

However, if you don't have access to the primitive getters then you could define `cost` as:

```hs
cost :: Getter Item Double
cost = to $ (*) <$> view quantity <*> view price
```

Your fingers don't need to move too far away from the home row in order to type out `view`.

Comment: I'm trying to combine lenses, because they might not correspond to record accessor, therefore using the primitive getters is out of question. However, I agree `view lens` is better `(^. lens)`.